# Possible options to deploy R application in AWS Environment

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, rstudio-server

I am looking for all the possible options to deploy an application written using R and the Shiny package on AWS. I see one of the options is to use EC2, but I would like to know if there is any serverless option available to deploy R applications on AWS.

Does Sagemaker RStudio have an option to deploy? I looked into AWS documents, but unfortunately I could not see an option.

Any leads would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's tons of options from various cloud providers. You can containerize, use a service like shinyapps.io, use cloud servers, local servers, etc.

Comment: @cory I am looking for options within AWS

Answer (score 0):

Using RStudio on SageMaker (or simply R kernels in SageMaker Studio / Notebooks) enables several deployment strategies for RESTful application endpoints.

In this example, you can see a trained R model deployed to a SageMaker serverless endpoint:
https://github.com/aws-samples/rstudio-on-sagemaker-workshop/blob/main/03_SageMakerPipelinesAndDeploy/01_Pipeline.Rmd#L124-L149

In this example, you will deploy a trained R model to a 24/7 RESTful endpoint using SageMaker real-time endpoints:
https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/r_examples/r_serving_with_plumber

In order to build the serving containers for those models, you can check the above examples or you may want to use recently launched functionality using the native R vetiver package:
https://github.com/juliasilge/vetiverdemo/blob/main/biv-svm/train_sagemaker.Rmd

If you're looking to deploy shiny applications and not models, you can use EC2 or a container service like ECS/Fargate to host the Shiney or RStudio connect server. These blogs may be a bit overkill for what you're looking to do, but they should have good examples of achieving hosted applications:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/host-rstudio-connect-and-package-manager-for-ml-development-in-rstudio-on-amazon-sagemaker/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/scaling-rstudio-shiny-using-serverless-architecture-and-aws-fargate/